# How to get Group node in Alfresco 3.1's Java-Backed Webscript

Tags: java, alfresco

With Javascript Webscript, I can get a group node with the following code:

```
var group = People.getGroup(groupname);
```

What would be the Java-backed equivalent of this code?

So far I can only get a set of all group names, but I would like to be able to iterate through the set and get the actual group node.

```
//Gets all groups, but only as a set of groupnames
Set<String> groups = new HashSet<String>();
groups.addAll(authorityService.getAllAuthorities(AuthorityType.GROUP));
for (String groupname : groups) {
  //jscript equivalent - var group = People.getGroup(groupname);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `org.alfresco.repo.security.authority.AuthorityDAO` `getAuthorityNodeRefOrNull` method to get a group node by the name.

Unfortunately the AuthorityDAO doesn't provide a method to get all group node, but if you look at the code of it's implementation org.alfresco.repo.security.authority.AuthorityDAOImpl you'll be able to easily copy the code that does it, it's not very complex.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately I was pressed for time and ended up using the javascript webscript equivalent for this particular component.  If I have some time, I probably will try it out in java again.  As a beginner, its hard to find my way around the api sometimes due to the lackluster documentation.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: That's true, it's not easy to find this kind of stuff in the Alfresco API.
What i usually do is search on the Alfresco source code for what i want. That's how i found about the AuthorityDAO.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer.  I thought I had a while back when I wrote out my first reply.  Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

There's a new AuthorityService method coming soon that'll give you the noderef for a given group:

```
/**
 * Gets the authority node for the specified name
 * 
 * @param name The authority name
 *  
 * @return the reference to the authority node
 */
public NodeRef getAuthorityNodeRef(String name);
```

It's not in a released version of Alfresco though, so for now you'll need to call  getAuthorityNodeRefOrNull from a AuthorityDAO as Hugo suggested.